# How to create silverlight application with ASP.NET MVC project

Tags: visual-studio, silverlight

I have visual studio 2012. At an application creation of silverlight there has to be a possibility of a choice of the asp.net mvc project, but I offer only the asp.net webforms projects. How to correct it?

Comment: Don't choose any project, then add mvc project to the solution manually, then in mvc project properties open the silverlight tab and add your application.